# change the icon of a custom post type in WordPress to use twitter boostrap

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Using jquery, the icons of WordPress admin menu have been changed to use the twitter boostrap icons, done such as:

```
jQuery('#icon-themes.icon32').replaceWith('<div style="font-size:22px;" class="icon32 fonticon"><i class="icon-eye-open icon-large"></i></div> ');
```

But I have custom post type icons that I want to replace with icons from twitter boostrap. The problem is I am not sure what to target.

The source code for one looks such as: (this is for one menu item, which is a custom post type)

```
  <ul>
    <li class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-mini-feed" id=
    "menu-posts-mini-feed"><a href='edit.php?post_type=mini-feed' class=
    "wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-mini-feed" aria-haspopup=
    "true"></a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="wp-menu-arrow"></div>

  <div class='wp-menu-image'><img src=
  "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fatcow/farm-fresh/32/folders-icon.png" alt=
  "" /></div>

  <div class='wp-menu-name'>
    Mini-Feed
  </div>

  <ul class='wp-submenu wp-submenu-wrap'>
    <li class='wp-submenu-head'>Mini-Feed</li>

    <li class="wp-first-item"><a href='edit.php?post_type=mini-feed' class=
    "wp-first-item">All Mini-Feeds</a></li>

    <li><a href='post-new.php?post_type=mini-feed'>New Mini-Feed</a></li>
  </ul>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Try intercepting the `$submenu` and `$menu` variables and assign your own classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always like using [this tutorial](http://randyjensenonline.com/thoughts/wordpress-custom-post-type-fugue-icons/) which would give you this code.

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_head', 'cpt_icons' );
function cpt_icons() {
    ?>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        #menu-posts-POSTTYPE .wp-menu-image {
            background: url(<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/YOURIMAGE.png) no-repeat 6px -17px !important;
        }
    #menu-posts-POSTTYPE:hover .wp-menu-image, #menu-posts-POSTTYPE.wp-has-current-submenu .wp-menu-image {
            background-position:6px 7px!important;
        }
    </style>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: jQuery('#menu-settings .wp-menu-image').replaceWith('<div style="font-size:18px;" class="icon16 fonticon"><i class="icon-cogs"></i></div> ');

Comment: Is the jQuery above the way you ended up doing it? My way ALSO works but the beauty of WordPress is there are more then one way to do things. If the JQuery above is what you used please answer your own question and mark it "correct."